# "Удивить своим ответом" or "со своим ответом"?

Tags: грамматика

Which one of following two sentences is right?

> Девушка всех удивила своим ответом

or

> Девушка всех удивила со своим ответом

I remember reading about when to add the 'с' it was in Russian and I cannot get the info.
It was a sort of general rule it goes like 'if you delete the adjective and the sentence doesn't make sense then it has to be with the "c".

Comment: _"Девушка всех удивила со своим ответом"_ can be understood as _"A girl and her answer surprised everyone"_, which is more special and rare sentence construction in comparison to more common _"Девушка всех удивила своим ответом"_ = _"A girl surprised everyone with her answer"_.

Comment: Agree with @DK. If you are trying to translate "with her answer" you say "своим ответом". Her answer is the instrument by which she astonishes. If she astonished everyone with her sister you would say "со своей сестрой". Her sister is her partner. Making her answer her partner would be "special and rare sentence construction". It would mean something like: "That girl coming along as she did with an answer like that in tow astonished everyone."

Comment: @David42 thanks, well that kind of construction is sometimes used to elaborate or emphasize a particular subject. Like you can say "Как же мне надоел февраль со всем этим снегом." meaning that you are tired of "February and all that snow".

Answer (score 1):

Девушка всех удивила **своим ответом**.

Удивила (чем?) своим ответом, это творительный падеж (creative case)

Comment: Он говорит с испанским акцентом или

Comment: Он говорит хриплым голосом или с хриплым голосом

Comment: @deEgea вам дали правильный ответ - что касается ваших комментариев то правильно "он говорит с испанским акцентом" и "он говорит хриплым голосом" - так и только так.

Comment: De Egea  говорить хриплым голосом — speak with a croak . Russian and English constructions do not coincide, just consult a dictionary.

Comment: Творительный падеж - [Instrumental case](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instrumental_case).

Answer (score -1):

"Девушка всех удивила со своим ответом".
in fact, it looks more likely (and can be like this) as two separated phrases, the second phrase is unfinished.

"Девушка всех удивила, со своим ответом как дурачок с писаной торбой ..."

"Девушка всех удивила, со своим ответом... етить его в качель... "

"Девушка всех удивила, со своим ответом... потрясая им, как дубиной... не знаю что, - разрушила все гипотезы оппонентов"

Otherwise, it's just the mistaken form.